# MYSQL Restoring large DB into Remote Server

Tags: mysql

Hi All,

I am trying to restore nearly 8GB DB into remote server using mysql command in command prompt. It is been 8 hours since i started the process. But it still restores the DB. I tried with the command

```
> mysql -h hostname -u username -p dbname < location of the dump file
```

My questions are,

1. Does it take these much hours time to restore these amount of DB?
2. Is it possible to restore 8GB database?
3. Am i doing in correct way?
4. Is there any other better way to restore the DB?

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Which tool you used to take the backup?

Comment: @mpe I tried usual restoring option from command prompt.

Comment: Please be more specific. `mysqlimport`? `mysql < dump.sql`? By the way, yes, 8 GB can take a few hours to finish, especially when indexes are involved.

Comment: @mpe see i have edited my post with the command i tried

Comment: Can you start another terminal window and take a look at the DB? There should probably be *some* tables by now. Also, `top` should tell whether the process is running

Comment: @Pekka웃 ya. i can see some tables and the process is still going. My worry is, do we have any other method to make this fast?

Comment: Unless any other processes on the server are eating up your resouces, I guess the only way to speed things up is to buy a faster server. :)  I would just wait it out.

Comment: Like I said, 8 GB is a large amount of data. Bite the bullet and wait.

Comment: So, there is no way. Thanks Guys for your suggestions.

Comment: log in to another session for the same server and do a 'show processlist' - make sure it's not stuck.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the answer of @Ferri is good, in cases like this the CLI is always the best option.

The only improvement that I suggest is to use gzip to reduce the weight of the script.

Dump the db like so:

```
mysqldump --host yourhost -u root --port 3306 -p yourdb | gzip -9 > yourdb.sql.gz
```

Restore the db like so:

```
gzip -cd yourdb.sql.gz | mysql -h yourhost -u root -p yourdb
```

Answer (score 1):

Command

```
mysql -h IP -u Username -p schema < file
```

Example

```
mysql -h 192.168.10.122 -u root -p mydatabase < /tmp/20160628_test_minificated.sql
```

**Does it take these much hours time to restore these amount of DB?**

Depends of size of dumpfile and connection speed.

**Is it possible to restore 8GB database?**

Yes, by this way you can restore big databases.

**Am i doing in correct way?**

For me this is the best way when you are working from command line interface and destination also is a command line interface.

**Is there any other better way to restore the DB?**

Yes you have multiple options, like phpmyadmin, workbrench, heidisql and many others but each one have their own limitations.